# Best way to handle SIGKILL in Linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm writing a syscall in Linux 3.0, and while I wait for some event to occur (using a waitqueue), I would like to check for a pending SIGKILL and if one occurs, I would like for the `current` task to die as soon as possible. As far as I can tell, as soon as I return from the syscall (well, really: as soon as the process is to enter into user mode) returns, the kernel checks for pending signals and upon seeing the SIGKILL, the kernel will kill `current` before it returns to user mode.

Question: Is my above assumption correct about how SIGKILL works? My other option is to see that the fatal SIGKILL is pending, and instead of returning from the syscall, I just perform a `do_exit()`. I'd like to be as consistent as possible with other Linux use cases...and it appears that simply returning from the syscall is what other code does. I just want to ensure that the above assumption about how SIGKILL kills the task is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signal checking happens after system call exit, yes.

See e.g. `ret_from_sys_call` at `arch/x86/kernel/entry_64.S`.